# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' (beginner coding)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the output be the temperature of the user-inputted city convert from C to F. This is the current code:

```
Cityname = input("Put a city name here: ")

Temp = input("Whats the tempin Celsius?: ")

CeltoFar = ((9/5 * Temp) + 32)

print("The temp in " + Cityname + "is, in Farenheit," + CeltoFar)
```

And after inputting the temperature I come with the error in the title. Adding float to various places didn't help so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

adding a float function before the equation didnt help and adding an int function got a different error entirely:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Comment: `Temp` is a string, not a number.

Comment: The method `input` returns a string. You need to convert the `str` value to `float`: `float(Temp)`. And of course you may want to check validity of the input, that is, if the string is a numeric representation. Something like `float("ABC")` will fail.

Comment: Oh, and you cannot concatenate `str` to non-str values so that print statement will fail. Use `f-string` instead